# jQuery validate a numeric range (without using a plugin) after keyup and blur fires

Tags: jquery

In this example, let's assume we have one textbox and the requirement is to allow only numeric values between 5 and 15. Furthermore, we must validate on keyup and blur. In this case scenario, let's assume the user tried to enter the number 12. Let's not worry about !$.isNumeric() etc. right now. You get the idea. Both events fire on the 1st key stroke and fails because 1 is < 5. The user must be able to enter 12. \m/ \m/

```
var bAlertCalled = false; 

$("someTextbox").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
    if (validateRange(5, 15, parseInt($(this().val()))) === false) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
    else {
        // Valid range entered. Do something.
    }
});

function validateRange(iRangeMin, iRangeMax, iValue) {
    //  Both keyup and blur will fire. This prevents 2 alerts from displaying.
    if (bAlertCalled === true) {
        bAlertCalled = false;
        return;
    }

    if ((iValue < iRangeMin) || (iValue > iRangeMax)) {
        bAlertCalled = true;
        alert('Please enter a numeric value between 5 and 15.');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the complication here is that you haven't clearly defined the use case for when/why you want to notify the user their input is invalid.If there's no "validate" button that the user clicks, and you want to be able to notify them of invalid values as they type, you have to show "1" as being invalid, regardless of whether or not they intend to enter a "2" next. If there's a delay on the validation, say 1 second, most people would type 1 and 2 within that limit. But if they wait too long, showing "1" as invalid would be a reasonable validation rule, IMHO.

Comment: The when, is on keyup and blur. The why, is the requirement. In this example, the user must enter a numeric value between 5 and 15 and we will alert them on the fly before submit. A delay is cool but do not want to rely on that unless there is no hope. Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem, I wasn't really clear enough in my comment. I mean to say that if you don't want "1" to instantly be invalid, i.e. if the user intends to enter a "2", then when should "1" become an invalid input? If not on keyup and blur, then on the click of a button perhaps? At some point 1 needs to trigger as invalid.

Comment: Just to clarify a little more, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkbt2/3/) to illustrate the behavior of adding a delay to the error validation. It might not be perfect, but hopefully it's close to your desired result. I agree `.delay()` is not a great solution to most things, but when it's purely used for visual animations, there are only a few gotcha's to watch out for, most notably the use of `.stop()`, and my fiddle's animation is so simple that I'm comfortable using `.delay()`.

Comment: Good call on the delay! Thanks. I ended up using a delay function and will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your input. Some good ideas helped towards a solution. Here is some pseudo code.

```
var bAlertCalled = false;

$("someTextbox").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
    //  Both keyup and blur will fire. This prevents 2 alerts from displaying.
    if (bAlertCalled === true) {
        bAlertCalled = false;
        return;
    }
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        var obj = $(this);

        delay(function () {
            if (validateRange(5, 15, parseInt(obj.val())) === false) {
                obj.select();
            }
            else {
                // Valid range entered. Do something.
            }
        }, 500);
    }
});

function validateRange(iRangeMin, iRangeMax, iValue) {
    if ((iValue < iRangeMin) || (iValue > iRangeMax)) {
        bAlertCalled = true;
        alert('Please enter a numeric value between 5 and 15.');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;

    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```